# How to install TP-LINK TL-WN722N on Debian Bullseye/11?

Tags: debian

I've tried this, but it did not work:

```bash
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install firmware-atheros

$ lscpi

  03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you reboot after installing firmware-atheros? Does it show up in `iwconfig`?

Comment: try lsusb - this is a USB device and won't show up on lspci. It might not *necessarily* be atheros either.. [V1](http://en.techinfodepot.shoutwiki.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN722N_v1.x) is atheros. [V2](http://en.techinfodepot.shoutwiki.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN722N_v2) may be realtek.

Comment: no, @harrymc
```
sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: i dont get it @JourneymanGeek
ive run lsusb
```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0c45:7603 Microdia USB Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

```

Answer (score 0):

I found the firmware in a non-free repository ([source](https://packages.debian.org/buster/firmware-atheros)):

1. Add `main contrib non-free` to `/etc/apt/source.list`:

   ```
   deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
   deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free

   deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main contrib non-free
   deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main contrib non-free

   deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
   deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
   ```
2. For TL-WN722N v1.x install Qualcomm Atheros firmware

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install firmware-atheros
   ```
3. For TL-WN722N v2 & v3 install Realtek firmware

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install firmware-realtek
   ```

Comment: i tried it and it does not work :(
nothing change, still with no connection

Comment: @hiwyn in hardware rev 2 and 3 you need to install `firmware-realtek`, as the chipset was changed from qualcomm to realtek.